# [Excel VBA]Select range from Excel and insert into Access database

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table constructed in Excel to be pasted later(after manipulation) into an Access table. It works with copy-paste in Windows, but I want to automate the process. We are talking about a large number of columns(A:AY) and a large number of records(10.000). I've seen it done with ADO recordset but only row by row. Is there a bulk method?

```
`Public Sub Test()
Dim connDB As New ADODB.Connection
'Dim rng As Range

strDBName = "Kiian.mdb"
strMyPath = "d:\Work\kiian"
strDB = strMyPath & "\" & strDBName

Dim xlXML             As Object
Dim adoRecordset      As Object
Dim rng               As Range

'this is a trick I found on the boards to easily create a recordset from range 
'without a connection, but it creates an object, not a recordset 
Sheets("mdb all").Activate
Set rng = Range("A1:ay3")
Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)
adoRecordset.Open xlXML

connDB.Open ConnectionString:="Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & strDB

'delete records in the PVAnag Table:
strSQL = "INSERT INTO PVAnag SELECT * FROM adoRecordset"
'connDB.Execute CommandText:=strSQL
connDB.Execute strSQL, nr

MsgBox (nr)

'Sheets("mdb_all").Range("A1:AY3").CopyFromRecordset rstData
'close the objects
connDB.Close

'destroy the variables
Set adoRecSet = Nothing
Set connDB = Nothing
End Sub
```

`
So basically, what i need is this: specify a range from a sheet and block insert that into an Access table. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Do you have an error with the code above ? Where ?

Comment: There wasn't any error, just that it didn't do anything, but I've left this approach in the dust because it was unnecesarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method (that I haven't tested) it could be to use Access objects in your Excel project. A very fast to import Excel files in Access is **DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet**.
You can have use this by referencing *Microsoft Access Object XX.0* (XX.0 is the version installed in your system).
Then, in code you have something like:

```
Dim db AS Access.Application
Set db = new Access.Application

db.OpenCurrentDatabase filepath="D:\Database1.accdb", Exclusive:=True
db.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet 'all_params_here

db.CloseCurrentDatabase
db.Quit acQuitSaveAll
```

Details about the function [DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head for a couple of hours trying to use TransferSpreadsheet, i found a clue on another forum and I came up with this:

```
Public Sub a()

Sheets("mdb all").Select
Range("a1:ay3").Select
Selection.Copy

strDBName = "Kiian.mdb"
strMyPath = "d:\Work\kiian"
strDB = strMyPath & "\" & strDBName

Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
' Open database in Microsoft Access window.
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strDB
appAccess.Visible = True

appAccess.DoCmd.OpenTable "PVAnag", acViewNormal, acEdit
appAccess.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPasteAppend

appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
appAccess.Quit acQuitSaveAll

End Sub
```

This method uses the clipboard and just copies from Excel, opens Access and pastes(special=append). For whatever reason, I just couldn't get TransferSpreadsheet to work. But thanks for the input and for getting me off my idea to use SQL.

Comment: Is there any way to view the number of records affected with this method?