# Populate an Access recordset from an Excel recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

I'm creating  a connection to an Access empty table

```
 Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    On Error GoTo ooo:
    direct = Range("Root") & Range("MdbTemplate")
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & direct & "\DbTargetTemplate.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password="
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    objRecordset.Open strSQL, con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Then a connection to an Excel one

```
strSQL = "[DATABASE$]"
                Set con = New ADODB.Connection
                con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
                RawData = "c:\Users\User\OneDrive\Word\Afek\Afek101.xlsm"
                con.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & RawData & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""")
                Set objRecordsetXL = New ADODB.Recordset
                objRecordsetXL.Open strSQL, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

**How do I populate the access table with the Excel objRecordsetXL?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[Excel VBA\]Select range from Excel and insert into Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906778/excel-vbaselect-range-from-excel-and-insert-into-access-database)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't assume Access installed

Comment: And your connection code accommodates that? How is connection different from that in suggested solution?

Comment: Yes. "Set con = New ADODB.Connection" doesn't require Access being installed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code to open recordsets works, try looping objRecordsetXL, set objRecordset to AddNew mode, set fields = to objRecordsetXL fields, Update objRecordset, repeat. Something like:

```
Do While Not objRecordsetXL.EOF
    objRecordset.Addnew
    objRecordset("field1name") = objRecordsetXL("field1name")
    objRecordset("field2name") = objRecordsetXL("field2name")
    objRecordset.Update
    objRecordsetXL.MoveNext
Loop
```