# Can't save dataset from excel to access database c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I try to read excel file without open and fill it to dataset (for futher using), then I will save dataset to access database.

Here is my code

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//Read data from excel file and store to dataset
var ExcelfileName = @"C:\Users\gsa81hc\Desktop\COEMInternalErrataTracking_withCQnumber.xlsx";
var ExcelcnnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ExcelfileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\"";
var Excelcnn = new OleDbConnection(ExcelcnnString);
Excelcnn.Open();
var cmd = Excelcnn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [GEN4 Proejects$] ";
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(ds);

//Save dataset to access database
string AccesscnnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Tool_Development\CSharp\Dot2Wpf\Project_Database.accdb";
var Accesscnn = new OleDbConnection(AccesscnnString);
Accesscnn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", Accesscnn);
var objCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
objCommandBuilder.QuotePrefix = "[";
objCommandBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]";
da.Update(ds, "Table");
```

When I debug, ds has data but I don't know why when da.update can't save ds to access file

Comment: From memory, you cant update from one data source to another, you have to create a new dataset and then create row by row from the source the target.

Comment: Hi @TomC What's happen if I have 1 100 columns? I guess I need to redefine target's columns base on source and then add/update row by row from src to target. Is there any fast way to achieve it?

Comment: I created some pretty simple helper functions for this. Once its done once you can forget about it. But someone else might have another idea - as I said I'm working from my memory of transferring data from one data source another. Someone else might have another idea.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906778/excel-vbaselect-range-from-excel-and-insert-into-access-database